# Sprockets::FileNotFound at / couldn't find file 'action_cable' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to ROR and working through a sample page but am experiencing the following error when I go to localhost:3000

**couldn't find file 'action_cable' with type 'application/javascript'
   Checked in these paths: <...>**

I'm not sure what is causing this/how to fix but if I add "layout false" to my controller file then everything works ok.  Below are the files:

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

# Rails defaults
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'web-console'
gem 'spring'
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.5'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
gem 'sqlite3'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

View file:

```
 <h1>Home</h1>
 <p>Welcome to the home of <%= @owner.name %>. </p>
 <p>I was born on <%= @owner.birthdate %>
 <p>Only <%= @owner.countdown %> days until my birthday!</p>
```

Model File:

```
class Owner
    def name
            name = 'Foobar Radigan'
    end

        def birthdate
            birthdate = Date.new(1990,12,22)
        end

        def countdown
                today = Date.today
                birthday = Date.new(today.year, birthdate.month, birthdate.day)
                if birthday > today
                        countdown = (birthday - today).to_i
                else
                        countdown = (birthday.next_year - today).to_i
                end
        end

end
```

Controller file:

```
 class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
        # Do not use layout
        # layout false

    def new
            Rails.logger.debug 'DEBUG: entering new method'
            @owner = Owner.new
            render 'visitors/new'
            Rails.logger.debug 'DEBUG: owner name is ' + @owner.name
    end

end
```

*Note that if uncomment the 'layout false' line everything works, but I have no layout.

Comment: Try changing gem 'rails', '4.2.4' to gem 'rails', '5'

Answer (score 4):

SHORT ANSWER:

Just delete *cable.js* in */app/assets/javascripts/* and that should fix the problem.

LONG ANSWER:

To make sure you don't have this problem reappearing, here's a bit of retrospective speculation.

My guess is that you have RoR 5.x installed in your system globally, and after you generated what you thought was a 4.x RoR app using

```
#rails _4.x.x_ new app_name
```

you ended up having a 5.x RoR app instead. Now, even if you manually update Gemfile indicating that you need rails 4.x.x, your project will 
still have some leftovers, one of which being a cable.js file. That's how I think you got the error you see.

Now, how to avoid this. From what I understand, the above method of enforcing the older rails version is undocumented and not always works. Here's another method that surely works.

Suppose you have a 5.x RoR installed globally and want to enforce RoR v.4.x.x for a project called rails4_app, then:

```
#mkdir rails4_app
#cd rails4_app
#echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
#echo "gem 'rails', '3.2.17'" >> Gemfile
#bundle install
#bundle exec rails new . --force --skip-bundle
#bundle update
```

And here you go - now you have your rails 4.x.x app bootstrapped.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed a downgrade from Rails 5 to 4 (trying to use jruby with postgres... #pita) and this has saved my bacon!

Answer (score 0):

ActionCable is a feature of Rails 5, but you specified Rails 4 in your Gemfile

Comment: Is there an alternative to upgrading to rails 5?

Comment: Not really, that one of the killer features of Rails 5... You can try to integrate `faye` right into the app, but it will require you to have a threaded server, such as `thin`. In most cases the most simple solution is to use a node.js app which serves the websockets and communicate to rails app (the most easy solution is by using some pub/sub technology... for instance, redis offers that)